# C struct array default values

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    GPIO_TypeDef* GPIO_Reg;
    uint16_t GPIO_Pin;
    uint16_t status;
} PinType;
```

Then if I declare this array:

```
PinType array[10];
```

The `PinType` elements in the array are initialized with some default values?

For example, if I write this:

```
printf("%d", array[1].status);
```

Should I see `0` as output? Or the initial value depends on the content of the memory before I declared the array?

Answer (score 6):

This answer depends on the scope of the variable.

- if `array` is global, then it will be auto-initialized.
- if `array` is `static`, all the elements will be auto-initialized to `0`.
- if `array` is of `automatic` storage, it won't be initialized automatically.

Comment: Plus one; the first one is often forgotten

Comment: So if my array is global if i try to do that printf I should always receive a "0"? And if it is true, this is a feature i can rely on? I mean, it is in some way compiler-dependent or it is defined by the C standard?

Answer (score 2):

The structure members are **not** initialised, unless the variable is `static` or global.

In fact, using an uninitialised member is undefined behaviour in C.

`memset`ting the array with zeros is idiomatic.